# Greek letter sequence in axes (x-axis) plotting in R

Tags: r, plot, axes

I use R to plot a figure as follows

```
    grid=10
    library(matlab)
    lambda_grids=exp(linspace(log(1),log(1e-4),grid))
    plot(lambda_grids,type='l',xlab="", ylab="",yaxt="n")
```

By default, we can see axes (x-axis) taking 2, 4, 6, 8, 10.

I want axes showing sth like

```
  axes=expression(lambda[2],lambda[4],lambda[6],lambda[8],lambda[10])
```

Does anyone konw how to achieve this? Tks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your desired output, but you could achieve this by using `axis()` after you plotted your plot.

First you need to insert  `axes = FALSE` (no axes labels) and `frame.plot = TRUE` (frame around plot) in your `plot()` code like this

```
plot(lambda_grids, type = 'l', axes = FALSE, frame.plot=TRUE, xlab = "", ylab = "", yaxt = "n")
```

After that you use

```
axis(side = 1, at = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),labels = c(expression(lambda [2]), expression(lambda  [4]),
                                      expression(lambda  [6]), expression(lambda [8]), expression(lambda [10])))
```

And the output

[image]

Comment: I suspect the questioned wanted the expression given (meaning lambda's with subscripts) and just needed the `axis` & "labels" framework you have provided.

Comment: Exactly what I want! @Miha